# Return type of if block incompatibility in PineScript

Tags: pine-script

I have been fighting with PineScript for a while now trying to get an if block to compile. This is the current state of it, as I have unfolded all the functions, created auxiliary functions, separated portions into auxiliary series, and simplified the if block all the while still getting the same error. This is what I currently have (it was considerably more legible when I started down this rabbit hole):

```
C_(x,y) => [x,y]

float au1 = math.sqrt(math.abs(DD))/2
float au2 = D1/2
float aur = math.sqrt(au1*au1+au2*au2)
float aua = atan2(au2,au1)
[Cx,Cy] = if D0!=0 and DD>=0
        C_(math.pow((D1+math.sqrt(DD))/2,1/3.0),0.0)
    else if D0!=0 and DD<0
        float xo = math.pow(aur,1/3.0)*math.cos(aua/3.0)
        float yo = math.pow(aur,1/3.0)*math.sin(aua/3.0)
        C_(xo,yo)
    else if D0==0 and D1>=0
        C_(math.pow((D1+math.abs(D1))/2,1/3.0),0.0)
    else
        C_(math.pow((D1-math.abs(D1))/2,1/3.0),0.0)
```

And pine keeps replying with some version of the error:

> Return type of one of the 'if' or 'switch' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s) ([series float, series float]; [<#f2_arg0_type>, <#f2_arg1_type>]; [series float, series float]; [series float, series float])

Clearly it doesn't like the block that does a couple extra calculations.

I am at a loss on how to proceed. Any ideas?

---

As requested, here is a full snippet of code that reproduces the problem:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Foo")

// A couple routines
C_(float x, float y) => [x,y]

Cmul(x1, y1, x2, y2) => 
    float x = x1*x2-y1*y2
    float y = x1*y2+x2*y1
    [x,y]

// *******************************
// Problematic code
test(Cx,Cy) =>

    if not (Cx==0 and Cy==0)
        Cmul(Cx,Cy,-0.5,math.sqrt(3)/2)
    else
        C_(0,0)
    
// *******************************
m11 = ta.ema(close,24)

[A,B] = test(m11,m11)

plot(A, color = color.red , style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)
```

I believe I have found a solution, but it's still not obvious why.

Comment: Can you share a minimum reproducible example? I copied your code and had to add some stuff to make it compile. But it compiles fine for me.

Comment: That question of yours is much more helpful than you probably expected.... I am currently down a rabbit hole but the problem seems to be related to the number of function calls in a row. Substituting 0 for math.sin(0) removed the error, but moved it to a different line. I suspect I have an undefined variable somewhere. I'll update the question when i get a bit more clarity.

Comment: @BarisYakut I added the code, but I think I might have a solution, although I still don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're having trouble because if blocks expect the return variables/tuple to be the same. You need to explicitly declare the variable / tuple that is being returned. Then the tuple returned from the C_ & Cmul function is then passed through as the return for the test function correctly.

```
test(Cx,Cy) =>
    if not (Cx==0 and Cy==0)
        [ret1, ret2] = Cmul(Cx,Cy,-0.5,math.sqrt(3)/2)
    else
        [ret1, ret2] = C_(0,0)
```

Comment: That might work in this case, but I am almost sure I tried it in the actual code. The problem seems to be the dynamic typing unable to resolve the resultant type of the function calls before it examines the if statement. I got one part to work, for the same problem to pop up in the next conditional statement down the line.

Comment: I'd have to see what that code is doing to be able to tell you for sure, but for example maybe you could try predeclaring the test function's output variables (ie `float out1 = na, float out2 = na`) before the if block, then for each if block branch, you reassign the Cmul/C_ tuple variables to the predeclared variables before finally returning [out1, out2] outside the if block / function's root scope at the end.

Comment: That’s basically how I made it work. But I want to research it a bit more before I post it as an answer, as I am not sure exactly why it’s working now.

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering, the problem is with the way Pine Script deals with variable types. For some reason the functions are not able to resolve the type of its arguments and are left "raw" as the IF block checks the type of its results.

The solution that @rumpypumpydumpy posted works in this specific case, but the unevaluated functions propagate down the code causing further errors to be solved.

What I found is something that I am not sure is documented in Pine-Script manuals (I haven't explicitly seen it used), but it makes sense from many a language's perspective.

Change the declaration of the problematic functions to explicitly type their arguments like so:

```
Cmul(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) => 
    float x = x1*x2-y1*y2
    float y = x1*y2+x2*y1
    [x,y]
```

This way, the type resolution code can figure out what is the type of the resulting variables should be, removing all conflicts in the IF block and further down the code.